# problemas de orden en la pagina

Tags: php, html

Tengo un problema con el listado de HTML y PHP debido a que no me muestran los datos como corresponde

El objetivo es que me lo muestre de esta forma

[image: el objetivo es que la tabla muestre la lista de esta forma]

Pero me sale de esta forma

[image: pero me lo muestra de esta forma]

```
<form action="ListadoCompletoBuscarSensor1.php" >

        Nombre de la primera persona:
        <select name="nombre1">
            <?php
            $listado1 = $dao->ListadoPorPersona();
            foreach ($listado1 as $value) {
                echo "<option>" . $value . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>

        Nombre de la Segunda Persona
        <select name="nombre2">
            <?php
            $listado2 = $dao->ListadoPorPersona();
            foreach ($listado1 as $value) {
                echo "<option>" . $value . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>


        <input type="submit" value="Listar Por Sensor" name="btnListarPersona" />           
    </form>
    <?php
    $nombre1 = $_GET['nombre1'];
    $nombre2 = $_GET['nombre2'];        



    $r = $dao->ListadoAgrupadoPorPersona($nombre1, $nombre2);

    echo '<table class="table-fill">';


    echo '<th class="text-left">' . $nombre1. '</th>' .
    '<th class="text-left">' . $nombre2. '</th>' .


    foreach ($r as $list) {

        if ($list->getEquipo() == $nombre1) {
            foreach ($r as $value) {
                echo '<tbody class="table-hover">';
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td class="text-left">' . $value->getValor() . '</td>';
                //echo '<td class="text-left">' . $value->getFecha().  '</td>';
            }
        }
        if ($list->getEquipo()==$nombre2) {
            foreach ($r as $value) {
                echo '<td class="text-left">' . $value->getValor() . '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
                echo '</tbody>';
            }
        }
        echo '</table';
    }
```

> 

Comment: suena a un mal diseño de la tabla. y es muy probable que se causado porque abres los TR dentro de un if, y los cierras dentro de otro. aparte de que estan incluidos dentro de un for...

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara: _no me muestran los datos como corresponde_ **¿Qué datos?**. **¿Cómo es que corresponde mostrarlos?** También deberías indicar en que sistema de base de datos estás trabajando para tener una respuesta específica del mismo y muestra el código de la consulta a la BD.

Comment: Pregunta, en tu imagen muestras 4 columnas pero en tu código solo veo 2 de $senio1 y $senior2 podrías explicar algo mejor esa parte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema lo tienes en como estas construyendo la tabla, para que los datos se te armen de manera correcta tu código quedaría así:

```
echo '<table class="table-fill">';    
    echo    '<th class="text-left">' . $sensor1 . '</th>' .
            '<th class="text-left">' . $sensor2 . '</th>' .
    echo    '<tbody class="table-hover">';

    foreach ($r as $list) {
        echo '<tr>';
        if ($list->getEquipo() == $sensor1) {                
            foreach ($r as $value) {             
                echo '<td class="text-left">' . $value->getValor() . '</td>';
                //echo '<td class="text-left">' . $value->getFecha().  '</td>';
            }
        }
        if ($list->getEquipo()==$sensor2) {
            foreach ($r as $value) {
                echo '<td class="text-left">' . $value->getValor() . '</td>';                                        
            }               
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table';
```

Debes recordar que los ciclos son para llenar las filas "tr" de la tabla